# This query will give results in phpmyadmin but empty set in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT id FROM locations WHERE location_name='saint fran&ccedil;ois'
```

will give me a set[image]

but gives me an empty set when i use the query function of PDO

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->query("SELECT id FROM locations WHERE location_name='".htmlspecialchars(htmlentities(str_replace("'","\'",$get['location'])))."'");
```

Comment: What is the `datatype` and `Collation` of field `location_name` in your database ??

Comment: collation:latin1_swedish_ci and datatype:varchar(255)

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->dbh("SELECT id FROM locations WHERE location_name=?");
$stmt->execute([htmlentities($get['location'])]);
```

### But you should never store HTML entities in database.

Instead, you have to store your text as is, as `franÇois`
And query it without converting,

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->dbh("SELECT id FROM locations WHERE location_name=?");
$stmt->execute([$get['location']]);
```

you have to properly indicate the data encoding, either for the table and connection.